# If $f$ holomorphic such that $|f^{(n)}|\leq M$, then $f$ is a polynomial (verification)

Tags: complex-analysis

I know a similar question was asked here, but I just need a clarification of the proof, I have no problem deleting my question after I get it.

If $f$ holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq M$, then $f$ is a polynomial $\leq n$ degree.

Letting $g(z)=f^{(n)}(z)$ from liouville theorem we get $f^{(n)}(z)=c$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$

My question: is $f$ a polynomial by definition since the $n$-th derivative is a constant ? and the proof is complete or do I have to prove something more ?

Comment: it's not by definition. You have to prove that constant $n^{th}$ derivative implies it is a polynomial (but the proof isn't too hard). You have to prove the existence of $a_0,\dots, a_n\in\Bbb{C}$ such that for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$, $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k$.

Comment: Use induction on $n$.

Comment: No, it's not by definition. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121432/the-generalized-liouville-theorem#:~:) answer.