# If $f$ is entire and omits one value from $\Bbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq 2|z|^3$, $\forall |z|\geq 2$, then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be an entire and omits one value from $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq 2|z|^3,~\forall |z|\geq 2$. Then show that $f$ is a constant function.

I really don't have any idea to prove this. Kindly don't down vote it. Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial (of degree at most $3$) and non-constant polynomials assume all values.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can I get a proof of your comment?

Comment: Search this site. The fact that $f$ is a polynomial has been proved many times on this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **Picard's Little Theorem** If $f\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is entire, $f(\mathbb C)$ is either a singleton or contains the complement of singleton.

1. It suffices to show that all non-constant entire functions $f$ with $|f(z)|<=2|z|^3$ for $|z|\geq 2$ satisfy $f(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C$.
2. By the *generalized Liouville Theorem* (see the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121432/the-generalized-liouville-theorem)), $f$ is a polynomial.
3. It is equivalent to the *Fundamental Theorem of Algebra* that every non-constant polynomial $p\colon \mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is surjective.
4. By 3. we have that $f(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C$, and the conclusion follows from 1.

Comment: Thanks! you made my day